# Confused about using PHP composer and autoload

Tags: php

I am a newb to Composer and how best use it.

I have a library I am bringing up to date by introducing Namespaces and replacing all cURL calls by using the PHP Request lib Guzzle.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "description": "Description",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyClass\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Inside of `src/MyClass/API.php`, I have this

```
namespace MyClass;

require_once(dirname(dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) )).'/vendor/autoload.php');

use MyClass\Exceptions\MissingAccountId;
use MyClass\Exceptions\MissingAuth;
use MyClass\Exceptions\InvalidResponse;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

Why do I need to explicitly require `autoload.php`? Im a little confused about setting things up, so my apologies for the newb questions (I've been away from PHP programming for almost 4.5 years).

If I don't require `autoload.php`, then I receive an error of `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found`

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says. It autoloads the needed libraries as needed. This is needed, rather than doing a manual `require` for each needed libraries (which is usually done in the old way). The autoload.php file, automatically determines which classes is needed, and `require` the files to be loaded. This have the advantage of not needed to care about doing it manually and also reduce startup time since only the needed libraries are required.

Comment: That makes sense, but what's confusing is if you look at this example https://github.com/cubalider/unique/blob/master/src/internal/Uniqueness/ConnectToStorageInternalWorker.php#L5, they're not including an `autoload.php`, they are just mapping to the that lib via its namespace

Comment: It is assumed that the autoloader will be in play when that class is loaded... and more likely then not that class would have been loaded by the autoloader.

Comment: Got it. Ok, Im just trying to "paint a picture" for when/if someone uses my updated PHP class. Should I just leave that autoload require in there? Should I gitignore the vendor directory and composer.lock file?

Answer (score 0):

Even I am learning about Composer too, what I have recently learned is, Composer is used to:

1. Easy install/update the PHP Libraries in your script.(not exactly as yum or apt-get)
2. Making the actual package size of project smaller by not including them in our projects.
3. Single autoloader to load all libraries.

Before in the project/application we used to `require` or `autoload` each library, which was little hectic and not neat to manage the PHP libraries. So the composer.

Composer generate the autoloader file for you to include in your project. So coming to your question, you are configuring the composer.json(telling composer) to include the class `MyClass` in composer's autoloader.

Reference: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

If the vendor directory is fully managed by composer(which I prefer), mean no other library is installed manually. Then you don't need to push it to your repository(i.e you can add .gitignore).

PS: I have just tried to explain what I have understood till now about composer. Please feel free to correct or add to my answer. Even I am learning.